# O que significa os termos Memory Poisoning e HWPOISON?

Tags: linux, sistema-operacional, kernel

Estou estudando algumas coisas no kernel **GNU/Linux** e encontrei os termos acima nas seções de **Gerenciamento de Memória / Alocação de Memória**, gostaria de saber o significado de ambos e o que são ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por partes :)

## Qual a razão para os termos existirem?

Lá atrás em 2009, a Intel incluiu em seus processadores um novo mecanismo chamado de *Machine Check Architecture Recovery* (ou comumente chamado de *MCA Recovery*).

Este novo mecanismo tinha por objetivo fazer com que fosse possível o processador reportar falhas do hardware ao sistema operacional.

O sistema operacional por sua vez, ao receber um sinal de falha do processador, pode agir (ou não) para tratar do erro recebido e não apresentar um [kernel panic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic)

## Onde entra o HWPOISON nisso?

O HWPOISON é um *error handler* do Linux distribuído via patch, necessário para o tratamento dos erros apontados pelo processador e tratá-los de acordo. Estes erros são recebidos através de uma *Memory Check Exception*.

A exceção é tratada pelo sistema operacional e caso o valor encontrado nos registradores seja relacionada ao MCA e seja passível de recuperação, é repassada ao HWPOISON.

Um resumo retirado do artigo em referência:

> HWPOISON is a poisoned data handler invoked by the low-level Linux machine check code. Where possible, HWPOISON attempts to gracefully recover from memory errors, and contain faulty hardware to prevent future errors

## Ainda falta o Memory Poisoning

Então vamos pensar no seguinte, nós temos vários processos rodando no sistema, cada qual com seu gerenciando seus objetos na memória.

Quando o CPU envia um erro relacionado à memória ao SO, ele deve de alguma forma entender o que houve de errado, comunicar os processos que estão atualmente utilizando alguma região da memória que esteja apresentando problema, e ignorar a região para que ela não seja de fato utilizada.

Isso é chamado de Memory Poisoning, onde o SO marca a página de memória como "envenenada", busca todos os processos que estão relacionados à página e trata a memória de acordo para que os processos não sejam fechados, o relacionamento dos processos com estas páginas envenenadas é removido e as páginas são removidas.

No caso do Linux este é o trabalho do HWPOISON :)

> To recover from poisoned, user-mapped pages, HWPOISON first finds all user processes which mapped the corrupted page. For clean pages with backing store, HWPOISON need not take recovery action since the process does not need to be killed. Dirty pages are unmapped from all associated processes, which are subsequently killed.

O código fonte do HWPOISON pode ser visto [aqui](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ak/linux-mce-2.6.git/log/?h=hwpoison)

## Referências

[Memory Check Architecture Recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Architecture)

[Memory Check Exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception)

[HWPOISON Discussion](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/cover/151242/)

[HWPOISON Article](https://lwn.net/Articles/348886/)

[HWPOISON Repositório](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ak/linux-mce-2.6.git/log/?h=hwpoison)

[Memory Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory))

[Intel Architecture Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf)

- A seção 16.11.1.1 Processor Machine Check Status Register MCA Error Code Definition apresenta como os erros são tratados internamente no processador

Comment: muito bem respondido, obrigado por me dar um norte.. Irei dar uma leitura mais afunda nas referencias , juro que não imaginava que esses termos significariam isso :)